# Adding the numerator and denominator separately in a fraction.

Tags: fractions

We all know how to add two completely differently fractions, say we have fractions: -

$\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$

We know that: -

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + cb}{bd} $$

Suppose (hypothetically) we add the aforementioned fractions in a completely different way, say: -

$$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{a + c}{b + d} $$

We get a unique fraction $\frac{a + c}{b + d} $ whose value will **always** be in between the fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$.

My question is: -

Can someone give me the proof (mathematically) that the statement given below will be always true: -

$$\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d}$$

(where we assume that $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given 4 integers, $a, b, c, d > 0$, does $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ imply $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205654/given-4-integers-a-b-c-d-0-does-fracab-fraccd-imply-fra)

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891417/42969.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for showing me the answer, howsoever I am not able to upvote your comment?