# Is my proof of $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d} $ correct?

Tags: inequality, fractions, solution-verification

**Edit**: The original question lacked some constraints as saying that $ a $, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive and integers and that we know that $ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$. Thank you @Aqua and @LeeMosher for pointing out the flaws

--

I'm trying to prove that, given $ a $, $b$, $c$, $d$ positive numbers and integers, if:

$$ \frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d} $$

then:

$$ \frac{a}{b} <  \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d} $$

For that, I simplify the inequation, removing the denominators:

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} <  \frac{a + c}{b + d} < \frac{c}{d} \\
ad(b + d) < bd(a + c) < bc(b+d) \\
abd + ad^2 < abd + bcd < b^2c + bcd \\
ad^2 - bcd < 0 < b^2c - abd \\
\end{align}

Try to clear left side of the inequation for $ a $:

\begin{align}
ad^2 - bcd < 0 \\
a < \frac{bc}{d} \\
\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}
\end{align}

And, same for the right side of the inequation:

\begin{align}
0 < b^2c - abd \\
a < \frac{bc}{d} \\
\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}
\end{align}

Could I argue that this proves that: $ \frac{a}{b} <  \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$ ?

Comment: Related: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891417/prove-that-fracab-fracacbd-frac-cd).

Comment: Thank you, I edited my question based on that one.

Comment: Counterexample: let $a=b=c=1$ and $d=2$, so $\frac{a}{b} = 1 > \frac{1}{2} = \frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher $ \frac{a}{b} $ is less than $ \frac{c}{d} $

Comment: Then you should add that hypothesis to your question. Nowhere is that stated.

Comment: @LeeMosher, isn't implied if what we are trying to prove is a/b < a+c/b+d < c/d?

Comment: I agree that $$\underbrace{a/b < (a+c)/(b+d) < c/d}_Q \text{ implies } \underbrace{a/b < c/d}_P$$ And I understand that your intention is to prove the converse implication, namely that $a/b < c/d$ implies $a/b < (a+c)/(b+d) < c/d$ (with additional hypotheses pointed out by @Aqua). But when you are trying to prove a statement of the form "$P$ implies $Q$", you may not use *implications of $Q$* in your proof; that would make your proof circular. You must *always* state precisely what hypotheses you are assuming. To prove "$P$ implies $Q$", you must state $P$ as your hypothesis.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you. I understand now. The main problems when asking this question have been not specifying that $ a, b, c, d $ are positive and integers and that initially $ a/b < c/d $. I have edited the question.

Comment: There is an interesting "partial converse" to your question.  It can be shown that if $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers such that $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$.  Any rational number $r$ such that $\frac{a}{b}<r<\frac{c}{d}$ can be written in the form $$r=\frac{au+cv}{bu+dv}$$ where $u$ and $v$ are coprime positive integers.  Your problem is a special case where $u=v=1$.  $$ \phantom{a}$$  In fact, for all real numbers $a,b,c,d>0$ such that $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$, if $r$ is a real number such that $\frac{a}{b}<r<\frac{c}{d}$, then $r=\frac{ax+c}{bx+d}$ for some real number $x>0$.

Comment: So the requirement of the numbers being positive is not necessary after all. But the premise of  $ a/b < c/d $ is.

Comment: You need at least that $b$ and $d$ are positive.  For example, when $a=2$, $b=-1$, $c=-2$ and $d=2$, we have $$\frac{a}{b}=-2<-1=\frac{c}{d},$$ but $$\frac{a+c}{b+d}=\frac{2-2}{-1+2}=0$$ does not lie between $a/b$ and $c/d$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not correct since you don't know if the denominators are positive (or negative). Only then you can get rid of them (easly).

Correct would be:

$$ \frac{c}{d} - \frac{a+c}{b+d} = {(b+d)c-d(a+c)\over d(b+d)} = {bc-ad\over d(b+d)}$$

But we can not say nothing explicitly for the last fraction since we know nothing about $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean with: "we can say nothing explicitly for the last fraction since we know nothing about a,b,c,d"?

Comment: What that means is this. First, the quantity $bc-ad$ could be positive or negative. Second, the quantity $d$ could be positive or negative. Third, the quantity $b+d$ could be positive or negative. But we have not made any hypotheses about the values of $a,b,c,d$. So we can draw no conclusions about about the first, second, or third possibilities. So we can draw no conclusions about whether $\frac{bc-ad}{d(b+d)}$ is positive or negative. So we can draw no conclusions about whether $\frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Definitely I have missed an important part when writing down the question and is that $ a $, $b $, $c$, $d$ are integers and positive

Answer (score 1):

Yours is correct. Here is another approach:

Let $$k=\dfrac{a}{b}<\dfrac{c}{d}=l$$
Then
$$\dfrac{bk+dk}{b+d}<\dfrac{bk+dl}{b+d}<\dfrac{bl+dl}{b+d}$$
$$\iff \dfrac{a}{b}<\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}<\dfrac{c}{d}$$