# How to prove this inequality $\frac{a}{b}\leq \frac{a+c}{b+d}\leq \frac{c}{d}$

Tags: inequality

How can I show that for positive reals

$$
\frac{a}{b}\leq \frac{c}{d},
$$
that
$$
\frac{a}{b}\leq\frac{a+c}{b+d}\leq\frac{c}{d}.
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
ab+\color{red}{ad} \leq ab + \color{red}{bc} \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: similarly, $ad + cd \leq bc + cd$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{a+c}{b+d} <\frac{ c}{d}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891417/prove-that-fracab-fracacbd-frac-cd)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989104, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/205654, and some more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/205654

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks, this was a great hint!

Comment: Are you assuming $b,d > 0$. (which is a valid definition for the rationals-- that the denominators must be a positive natural number but the numerator may be any integer).  If $b,d$ may be any non-zero integers this needn't be true I think $\frac 1{-2}\le \frac 13$ but $\frac 1{-2} < \frac {1+1}{-2+3}; \frac {1+1}{-2+3} > \frac 13$.

Comment: @fleablood I forgot to mention that I was assuming all numbers to be positive reals.

Comment: So not merely integers.  Cool.  I think its true so long as $b,d$ are positive.  $a,c$ could be $0$ or negative and it'd still be true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}-\dfrac ab=\dfrac{ab+bc-(ab+ad)}{b(b+d)}=\dfrac{bd\left(\dfrac cd-\dfrac ab\right)}{b(b+d)}$$ which will be $\ge0$ if $\dfrac d{b+d}\ge0$

Comment: This must have been asked and answered at least a dozen times ...